# How to make the selected state icon appear in front of each menu item, similar to the UIKit UIAction selection state in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, uikit

To generate a SwiftUI context menu, I use the following code snippet (example 1). However, I noticed that unlike UIAction, the "checkmark" button is at the back by default. If I attempt to add an Image(systemImage: "check") in an HStack (example 2) before the Text, the icon still will not show up.

**SwiftUI**
[image]

**UIKit**
[image]

```
.navigationBarItems(
    leading: Button(action: { handleCloseClick() }) {
        Label("Close", systemImage: "xmark")
            .foregroundColor(Color("secondary"))
    },
    trailing:
    Menu(
        content: {
            Section(NSLocalizedString("filters", comment: "")) {
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Label(NSLocalizedString("a", comment: ""), systemImage: "checkmark")
                        .labelStyle(.titleAndIcon)
                }

                Button(action: {}) {
                    Label(NSLocalizedString("b", comment: ""), systemImage: "")
                }

                Button(action: {}) {
                    Label(NSLocalizedString("c", comment: ""), systemImage: "")
                }
            }

        },
        label: {
            Image(systemName: "line.3.horizontal.decrease.circle")
                .foregroundColor(Color("secondary"))
        }
    )
)
```

`Image` would not show in the `HStack`.

```
Section(NSLocalizedString("filters", comment: "")) {
    Button(action: {}) {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
            Text(NSLocalizedString("A", comment: ""))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @loremipsum, thank you for linking the question. I am trying to achieve it using pure SwiftUI. I know I probably can wrap a UIKit component to achieve the same, but I just want to make sure I did not miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use picker inside menu since picker default behavior put the check-mark for you and place it on the left side

the code should look like this :

```
@State private var sort: Int = 0
    var body: some View {

                    Menu {
                        Picker(selection: $sort, label: Text("Sorting options")) {
                                Text("a").tag(0)
                                Text("b").tag(1)
                                Text("c").tag(2)
                        }
                    }
                    label: {
                        Label("Sort", systemImage: "arrow.up.arrow.down")
                    }

    }
```

[image for the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt8To.jpg)